# My Numlock key light won't turn off when system Shutdown

Tags: shutdown, logout, numlock

Although my Numlock key still work, its light won't turn off when i shutdown the machine. The same thing happens with my wifi receiver. When the wifi turns off or system shutdown, the wifi receiver's  light still on. I'm using PC(Gigabyte motherboard H110M-DS2) with keyboard connected not built in.

PS: I'm Using Ubuntu 20.04 btw.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Which distribution and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: are you shutting down fully .. or going into hibernate or a hybrid sleep?

Comment: @user68186 Ubuntu

Comment: @JohnOrion fully Shutdown.

Comment: a) Which release of Ubuntu? b) What;s the make and model of the laptop? Please find the Model Part Number from the serial number sticker so we can zero on and find the right Hardware Reference Manual. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: ok. I edited, Im using Ubuntu 20.04 with additional keyboard pluged in not built in. Using Gigabyte MoBo (H110M-DS2)